# IE8 expected identifier error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

IE 7 & 8 throws an error (through jQuery): expected identifier

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.i18n.properties({
                    'name': "messages", 
                    'path': "/myproject/js/i18n/", 
                    'mode': "both",
                    'language': "en", 
                    'callback': function() {
                    }
    })
});
```

If I comment out line `'path': "/myproject/js/i18n/",` error disappears, but of course, i18n plugin stops working as expected.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure, but older IEs were not good with mixed quotes, try to use either single or double quotes, but not both in the same statement... Or you just have a non-printing character there?

Comment: Teemu, I tried double quotes, and it did not help; I will try single quotes though, tx for idea!

Comment: Teemu, single quotes did not help too.

Comment: Try deleting that entire line (including the leading and trailing line breaks to be safe) and retyping it.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Also, what does your config file look like? Have you tried using a simpler config file, maybe with only a couple of translations in it?

Comment: Spudley, jQuery 1.9.1 (but what is the difference?). What config file do you mean? messages.properties?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In messages.properties file there were lines like `something.delete.something=something`. These lines with 'delete' inside caused jQuery in IE7/8 to throw the error. I renamed these labels into `something.dodelete.something` and it worked.

Comment: 'delete' is a reserved word.  For a list, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords .  Generally, you can also do `something['delete'].something`

Comment: It doesn't explain though why only IE reacts to it such way. Besides, this word is used inside a label, which is I belive a string.

Comment: jquery.i18n-properties [generates](https://github.com/jquery-i18n-properties/jquery-i18n-properties/blob/master/jquery.i18n.properties.js#L322) a JavaScript function dynamically, then [evals it](https://github.com/jquery-i18n-properties/jquery-i18n-properties/blob/master/jquery.i18n.properties.js#L332) .

IE is failing on that eval.

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot rename, I suggest next:

```
response.responseJSON.messages.default
```

change to

```
response.responseJSON.messages['default']
```

Comment: good idea for reserved words. I am using the YT-lib with IE8. The error occured though he was not executed and protected by a try-catch-block