# How do you create a delete function prototype in javascript that works in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript

How do you create a delete function prototype in javascript that works in Internet Explorer?

I undestand that delete is a reserved word but the following works in some browsers.

For example, this works in Chrome:

```
function objName() {
...
 prototype.delete = function(name) {
        delete this;
    };
...
```

But it throws an "Identifier Expected" error in IE 11 at least.

After looking at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490398/ie8-expected-identifier-error/32780767#32780767) I tried changing it to

```
function objName() {
...
 prototype['delete'] = function(name) {
        delete this;
    };
...
```

which gets rid of the error in IE 11 but then the delete method does not work the same as it did before.

For example this does not work after changing it to `['delete']`:

```
objName.delete();
```

It is a requirement to use "delete" instead of something like "dodelete".

Comment: [`delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) is meant to delete properties of objects, not objects themselves. You code doesn't work in any browser.

Comment: `delete this;` makes no sense. Also objects are garbage collected automatically. If you want a delete function that does something else though, you can call it with `objName['delete']()`. Or use a post-processing step that does this conversion for you.

Comment: The code comes from [here](https://github.com/jerrybendy/url-search-params-polyfill) and I just simplified it for this post. It seems to be working now. It might have been related to IE switching to compatibility mode.

Comment: It looks like the browser was running in compatibility mode for an older version of IE where using reserved words as properties was not supported.